# Hta and webpage using functions from each other

Tags: html, hta

i have a webpage that i want to run through an hta.(that's the easy part)
i then want to have a button on my webpage that will run a function written in the hta is this possible?

if not, is it possible to use my webpage as a header and have the code written underneath in the hta. (Much like the php include statement.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've a HTA with an `iframe` which loads its content from web. You can try this:

```
<iframe application="yes" src="...">
```

If this won't help, you could try to use [postMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to interact with HTA.

Comment: @kriegy Well, then `postMessage` maybe the only way to achieve what you want.